# What counts as "Connected Media" for the Music player?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, htc-sense, networking, music

In the music app, there is a Connected Media tab. It shows up my router, a Belkin Play Max, but it does not show up my NAS device, which has an iTunes server and a "Media server" of unspecified protocol (at least it's not stated anywhere in the web interface). Neither of these show up.

What does this tab connect to?

EDIT: The device is the Desire HD running Android 2.2 as installed on it by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [HTC Support Page](http://www.htc.com/ca/support/desirez-bell/help/applications):

> **What is Connected Media and how do I use it?**
>
> This is a new application that allows you to play pictures, music and videos stored on your phone or on a media server to DLNA supported device such as a TV, Music player or even speakers. To access Connected Media All programs (button on the lower-left of the screen) > Connected Media.

So, anything that is [DLNA](http://www.dlna.org/) compliant should show up as a connected device.

Here is more information on [Connected Media](http://www.htc.com/europe/howto.aspx?id=8924&type=1&p_id=324) from HTC.